How would I go about creating a loop that tests variables in sequence to determine the source of the entry?
In creating a user form application where I enter in customer information, I want to have the information I type into the Entry boxes do two things: 1) Update in real time to a label off to the side of the application screen, and 2) update an Entry box specific variable that will be used to update the database at the appropriate time.
I have managed to accomplish what I wanted to do. However, in the interest of cleaning up the code, I would like to learn a simpler version involving a loop. When I type into one of the Entry boxes, it would trigger a function that tests the variables in sequence for that group of boxes to determine which one was changed, so that it can then update the appropriate Label and set a new value for the primary variable belonging to that box, which will be used to write to the database.
Right now I have a separate function for each Entry box. I'm sure there's a way to make a single function that all the boxes can tie to that can loop through the variables, test each change with an if statement, and then perform the necessary function when it discovers which box has been changed.
Below is a section of functional code to demonstrate generally what I'm doing.
import tkinter
app = tkinter.Tk()
app.configure(bg="#212325")
app.title("The Mobile Mechanic")
appw = 1370 #Width.
apph = 700 #Height.
scrw = app.winfo_screenwidth()
scrh = app.winfo_screenheight()
xpos = (scrw / 2) - (appw / 2)
ypos = (scrh / 2) - (apph / 2) #-48 pixels
app.geometry(f'{appw}x{apph}+{int(xpos)}+{int(ypos)}')

infofrm = tkinter.Frame(master=app, bg="#292d2e", width=230.8333333333333, height=690)
infofrm.place(x=5, y=5)

cstfrm = tkinter.Frame(master=app, bg="#292d2e", width=1123.666666666667, height=635)
cstfrm.place(x=240.8333333333333, y=60)

#Vehicle Information Display Frame
vehinfofrm = tkinter.Frame(master=infofrm, width=210.8333333333333, height=300, bg="#292d2e")
vehinfofrm.place(x=10, y=300)
    
def VIN_Display(event):
    CV1 = VINbox.get()
    VINlen = len(CV1)
    VINdisplay1 = tkinter.StringVar(master=vehinfofrm, value="")
    VINdisplay2 = tkinter.StringVar(master=vehinfofrm, value="")
    VINdisplay3 = tkinter.StringVar(master=vehinfofrm, value="")
    VINdisplbl1 = tkinter.Label(master=vehinfofrm, width=29, anchor="w", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7", textvariable=VINdisplay1)
    VINdisplbl1.place(x=1, y=0)
    VINdisplbl2 = tkinter.Label(master=vehinfofrm, width=29, anchor="w", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7", textvariable=VINdisplay2)
    VINdisplbl2.place(x=1, y=18)
    VINdisplbl3 = tkinter.Label(master=vehinfofrm, width=29, anchor="w", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7", textvariable=VINdisplay3)
    VINdisplbl3.place(x=1, y=36)
    if VINlen == 0:
        VINdisplay1.set("")
        VINdisplay2.set("")
        VINdisplay3.set("")
    if VINlen > 0 and VINlen < 18:
        if VINlen < 17:
            VINdisplay1.set("VIN: " + CV1 + " (Incomplete)")
            VINdisplay3.set(value="")
        if VINlen > 7:
            VINdisplay2.set("Engine Code: " + CV1[7])
        if VINlen == 17:
            VINdisplay1.set("VIN: " + CV1 + "")
            VINdisplay2.set("Engine Code: " + CV1[7])
            VINdisplay3.set("Last Eight: " + CV1[9:])

#Vehicle Listbox
vehlbl0 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Customer Vehicles", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl0.place(x=557, y=27)
custlstbox = tkinter.Listbox(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=34, height=5)
custlstbox.place(x=507, y=58.5)
    
#VIN Box
vehlbl1 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Vehicle VIN", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl1.place(x=437, y=163)
VINfrm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=208, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
VINfrm.place(x=507, y=163)
VINbox = tkinter.Entry(master=VINfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=33, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
VINbox.place(x=4, y=0)
VINbox.bind("<KeyRelease>", VIN_Display)
    
#License Plate Box
vehlbl2 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="License Plate", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl2.place(x=429, y=190)
LP1frm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=114, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
LP1frm.place(x=507, y=190)
LP1box = tkinter.Entry(master=LP1frm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=17, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
LP1box.place(x=4, y=0)
vehlbl3 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="State", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl3.place(x=637, y=190)
LP2frm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=42, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
LP2frm.place(x=673, y=190)
LP2box = tkinter.Entry(master=LP2frm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=6, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
LP2box.place(x=4, y=0)
    
#Fleet ID
vehIDlbl2 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Fleet ID", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehIDlbl2.place(x=458, y=217)
Fleetfrm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=114, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
Fleetfrm.place(x=507, y=217)
Fleetbox = tkinter.Entry(master=Fleetfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=17, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
Fleetbox.place(x=4, y=0)
    
#Year and Production Date
vehlbl4 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Year", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl4.place(x=474, y=253)
yrfrm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=46, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
yrfrm.place(x=507, y=253)
yrbox = tkinter.Entry(master=yrfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=6, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
yrbox.place(x=4, y=0)
vehlbl5 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Production Date", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl5.place(x=567, y=253)
proddtfrm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=52, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
proddtfrm.place(x=663, y=253)
proddtbox = tkinter.Entry(master=proddtfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=6, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
proddtbox.place(x=4, y=0)
    
#Make
vehlbl6 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Make", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl6.place(x=468, y=280)
mkfrm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=208, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
mkfrm.place(x=507, y=280)
mkbox = tkinter.Entry(master=mkfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=33, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
mkbox.place(x=4, y=0)
    
#Model
vehlbl7 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Model", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl7.place(x=463, y=307)
modfrm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=208, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
modfrm.place(x=507, y=307)
modbox = tkinter.Entry(master=modfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=33, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
modbox.place(x=4, y=0)
    
#Sub-Model
vehlbl8 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Sub-Model", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl8.place(x=438, y=334)
smfrm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=208, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
smfrm.place(x=507, y=334)
smbox = tkinter.Entry(master=smfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=33, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
smbox.place(x=4, y=0)
    
#Engine
vehlbl9 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Engine Size", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl9.place(x=438, y=361)
eng1frm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=54, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
eng1frm.place(x=507, y=361)
eng1box = tkinter.Entry(master=eng1frm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=7, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
eng1box.place(x=4, y=0)
vehlbl10 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Engine ID", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
vehlbl10.place(x=577, y=361)
eng2frm = tkinter.Frame(master=cstfrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=78, height=21, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
eng2frm.place(x=637, y=361)
eng2box = tkinter.Entry(master=eng2frm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=11, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
eng2box.place(x=4, y=0)
    
#
#Static Options
#
    
#Engine Specifics
engbuta = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
engbutb = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
engbutc = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
engbut1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(master=cstfrm, variable=engbuta, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#b2b4b7")
engbut1.place(height=20, x=502, y=396) #396
engbut1.configure(bg="#292d2e")
engbut2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(master=cstfrm, variable=engbutb, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#b2b4b7")
engbut2.place(height=20, x=580, y=396)
engbut2.configure(bg="#292d2e")
engbut3 = tkinter.Checkbutton(master=cstfrm, variable=engbutc, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#b2b4b7")
engbut3.place(height=20, x=658, y=396)
engbut3.configure(bg="#292d2e")
englbl1 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Diesel", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
englbl1.place(x=522, y=396)
englbl2 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Turbo", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
englbl2.place(x=600, y=396)
englbl3 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Hybrid", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
englbl3.place(x=676, y=396)
    
#Automatic or Manual
drivebut = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
drivebut1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivebut, value=1, bg="#b2b4b7")
drivebut1.place(height=20, x=502, y=423)
drivebut1.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivebut2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivebut, value=2, bg="#b2b4b7")
drivebut2.place(height=20, x=610, y=423)
drivebut2.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivelbl1 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Automatic", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivelbl1.place(x=522, y=423)
drivelbl2 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Manual", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivelbl2.place(x=630, y=423)
    
#Drive Wheels
drivewheelbut = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
drivewheel1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=1, bg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheel1.place(height=20, x=502, y=450)
drivewheel1.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivewheel2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=2, bg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheel2.place(height=20, x=502, y=470)
drivewheel2.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivewheel3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=3, bg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheel3.place(height=20, x=502, y=490)
drivewheel3.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivewheel4 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=drivewheelbut, value=4, bg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheel4.place(height=20, x=502, y=510)
drivewheel4.configure(bg="#292d2e")
drivewheellbl1 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="FWD", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheellbl1.place(x=522, y=450)
drivewheellbl2 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="RWD", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheellbl2.place(x=522, y=470)
drivewheellbl3 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="AWD", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheellbl3.place(x=522, y=490)
drivewheellbl4 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="4WD", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
drivewheellbl4.place(x=522, y=510)
    
#ABS
ABSbut = tkinter.IntVar(value=4)
ABS1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=ABSbut, value=1, bg="#b2b4b7")    
ABS1.place(height=20, x=610, y=450)
ABS1.configure(bg="#292d2e")
ABS2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=ABSbut, value=2, bg="#b2b4b7")
ABS2.place(height=20, x=610, y=470)
ABS2.configure(bg="#292d2e")
ABS3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=ABSbut, value=3, bg="#b2b4b7")
ABS3.place(height=20, x=610, y=490)
ABS3.configure(bg="#292d2e")
ABS4 = tkinter.Radiobutton(master=cstfrm, variable=ABSbut, value=4, bg="#b2b4b7")
ABS4.place(height=20, x=610, y=510)
ABS4.configure(bg="#292d2e")
ABSlbl1 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="2W-ABS", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
ABSlbl1.place(x=630, y=450)
ABSlbl2 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="4W-ABS", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
ABSlbl2.place(x=630, y=470)
ABSlbl3 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Non-ABS", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
ABSlbl3.place(x=630, y=490)
ABSlbl4 = tkinter.Label(master=cstfrm, text="Unspecified", bg="#292d2e", fg="#b2b4b7")
ABSlbl4.place(x=630, y=510)
    
#Save or Update Button
def on_enter(event):
    svvehbut.config(bg="#3393e2")
def on_leave(event):
    svvehbut.config(bg="#2369a2")
svvehbut = tkinter.Button(master=cstfrm, text="Save or Update Vehicle Record", width=28)
svvehbut.place(x=508, y=548)
svvehbut.configure(bg="#2369a2", fg="#d1d5d6")
svvehbut.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
svvehbut.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)
    
#Clear Button
def on_enter(event):
    clrvehbut.config(bg="#3393e2")
def on_leave(event):
    clrvehbut.config(bg="#2369a2")
clrvehbut = tkinter.Button(master=cstfrm, text="Clear Data or Selection", width=28)
clrvehbut.place(x=508, y=575)
clrvehbut.configure(bg="#2369a2", fg="#d1d5d6")
clrvehbut.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
clrvehbut.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

app.mainloop()

The functional part of this is the VIN. It does several things. A VIN is seventeen digits. If the VIN inputted into the Entry box is less than seventeen digits, the label reflects that the VIN is incomplete (you can sometimes type in sixteen digits and not realize you're missing one, so this was an important feature). Once the VIN reaches eight digits, the eighth digit is separated as the Engine Code (engines are classified by the eighth digit of the VIN). Once all seventeen digits are entered, it then separates out the last eight digits (dealerships use these when you call for parts). The other thing it does is set the variable CV1 (which is Customer Vehicle Box 1), which is what will be used for the database when I get that far.
So, the question is, is there a way for me to compact a variety of functions into a single function, and have it loop through variables [CV1, CV2, CV3, etc.] until it finds the box that has been changed, have it run the appropriate functions for the correct box, and set the appropriate variable for that box?
I CAN do this one function at a time. I've made it work, and I can make each of the other boxes work the same way. But, again, I'm trying to clean up the code and simplify it if it's possible. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'm not computer stupid, but I am new to this language, so please answer accordingly.

You can get the entry widget using event.widget inside VIN_Display(), therefore you can bind the same callback to different entry widgets.

Also you should create those StringVar and labels once outside the VIN_Display() and update them inside the function.  Currently new set of StringVar and labels are created whenever VIN_Display() is executed.
